# Move multiple commits (with merges in between) out of master into separate branch

Tags: git, github

Using git, I want to move all of the changes created by my own local commits (ace45b0 and 2d4ac36) to a single commit on a separate branch and remove those commits from master. Can I do this?

```
7ff6336 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merged remote master before pushing
2d4ac36 Made some local changes
bb60891 Merged upstream master into local master
b7a4d2e (upstream/master) Merge 271eb1a into upstream master
271eb1a Commit in another fork
ace45b0 Made some local changes
959d04b head when I first cloned.
```

I think I am after this final result:

```
origin/master        myNewBranch
bb60891 HEAD         <hash after applying ace45b0 & 2d4ac36> HEAD
b7a4d2e              bb60891 
271eb1a
959d04b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to cherry-pick the two commits from `master` to `myNewBranch`, then squash them down to a single commit in `myNewBranch`.  Finally, you can remove the original two commits from `master` by either doing a `git revert` (simple and safe), or possibly through an interactive rebase where you actually delete the commits from `master`.

First cherry pick the two commits to `myNewBranch`:

```
git checkout myNewBranch
git cherry-pick ace45b0
git cherry-pick 2d4ac36
```

Note that you may get merge conflicts with each cherry-pick, and if so, you will have to deal with them.

There are several options to squash these two new commits into a single commit.  An interactive rebase is perhaps the most powerful, but it is heavy duty, and since the two commits you want to squash are the HEAD or immediately prior to the HEAD, there is a much simpler option.  We can try doing a soft reset to two commits prior in the `myNewBranch` branch:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
```

This will move the HEAD pointer to the commit *before* the first of the two cherry-pick commits.  It will not update the stage or working directory, which means that the changes these commits introduced will now be staged.  Now all you have to do is to make a commit:

```
git commit -m 'brought in two commits from local changes'
```

Now to cleanup the `master` branch, most likely the best option for you would be to just revert the two commits, e.g.

```
git checkout master
git revert 2d4ac36
git revert ace45b0
```

This will add two *new* commits on top of `master` which will functionally cancel out what the two commits were doing.  This option is safe if your `master` branch is published and shared by someone other than yourself, because it does not actually rewrite history, it only adds new commits.

If no one else is sharing `master` then you have another option here.  You could do an interactive rebase of the `master` branch and delete the two commits.  If you can tolerate the risk associated with this, you can try the following:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~7
```

This will bring up a window showing the 7 most recent commits from the HEAD, from older to newer:

```
959d04b head when I first cloned.
ace45b0 Made some local changes
271eb1a Commit in another fork
b7a4d2e (upstream/master) Merge 271eb1a into upstream master
bb60891 Merged upstream master into local master
2d4ac36 Made some local changes
7ff6336 Merged remote master before pushing
```

Now *delete* the lines containing the two commits you don't want, leaving you with this:

```
959d04b head when I first cloned.
271eb1a Commit in another fork
b7a4d2e (upstream/master) Merge 271eb1a into upstream master
bb60891 Merged upstream master into local master
7ff6336 Merged remote master before pushing
```

Now save the windows (`:wq` if you are using Vim) and exit.  The should start the rebase.  Again, you could encounter merge conflicts along the way as Git replays old commits on top of a new base.  Once you have finished the rebase, your `master` branch will be completely devoid of the two original commits.  Again, this is only a really good option if `master` were not being shared by anyone else, as it requires rewriting history, unless the `git revert` option.

Comment: "If no one else is sharing master then... " I'm working only on my own local copy. Ultimately new branch will be sent as pull request to upstream. I'm pretty confident there no conflicts between my own changes and upstream master at present. I really just want master to look like I cloned it today, and branch to be my own work as a single step. I didn't know I could/should make PRs from a branch, so I merged to my own master making things harder. :)

Comment: you can reset hard your local master, but you'll lose those commits

Comment: Not sure what to make of your above comment, but one more thing I forgot to mention: If you go with the rebase option to remove the commits from `master`, then you will need to _force_ push this branch, e.g. `git push --force origin master`.  This is needed because the history has changed and GitHub will choke and reject otherwise.

Comment: So as long as nobody except me is using my fork, I should be able to cherrypick then rebase, and that's probably the cleanest result without starting over my own work?

Comment: @sop If you look closely at the commit history which the OP provided, you'l see that the two commits the OP wants to remove are buried below the `HEAD`.  Doing a hard reset would not work, not without throwing out many more commits.

Comment: @skylize Yes, cherry-pick should give you no trouble.  I like the soft reset option to squash your two commits.  Doing an interactive rebase also won't lead you astray, assuming you don't accidentally remove the wrong two commits.